# Datagram sent to gateway instead directly to destination host in local network

Tags: linux, networking, routing

As this was out of scope for [networkengineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84072/udp-datagram-sent-to-gateway-instead-directly-to-destination-host-in-local-netwo), let me ask this here again as this is related to the linux network stack.

I have following setup/situation:

```
            ---------------------
            |  Gateway          |
            | 10.1.0.1          |
            | aa:bb:cc:00:00:01 |
            ---------------------
                        |
---------------------   |  
|  Host 1           |---|
| 10.1.0.91         |   |
| aa:bb:cc:00:00:91 |   |
---------------------   |
                        |
---------------------   |
|  Host 2           |----
| 10.1.0.92         |    
| aa:bb:cc:00:00:92 |
---------------------
```

The subnetmask is `255.255.240.0`. Host1 and Host2 are Linux/Ubuntu nodes.

If I now send a datagram from Host1 to Host2, I would expect, that it would go directly there: ARP request for 10.1.0.92 to get the mac address for Host2, filling the datagram and off to the wire.

Interestingly I observe a different behavior: the datagram gets filled with the gateway's mac address instead, which is not what I expected.

This is the routing table from Host 1:

```
Host1 > ip route -n
default via 10.1.0.1 dev enp130s0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.91 metric 100 
1.1.1.1 via 10.1.0.1 dev enp130s0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.91 metric 100 
9.9.9.9 via 10.1.0.1 dev enp130s0 proto dhcp src 10.1.0.91 metric 100 
10.1.0.0/20 dev enp130s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.0.91 metric 100 
10.1.0.1 dev enp130s0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.1.0.91 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
```

This is the tcpdump output from Host1, where we see that the datagram is sent to the gateway:

```
Host1 > tcpdump -en -i enp130s0 udp and port 12345
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on enp130s0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
07:22:10.249224 aa:bb:cc:00:00:91 > aa:bb:cc:00:00:01, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 60: 10.1.0.91.42518 > 10.1.0.92.12345: 18533 updateMA [b2&3=0x6c6c] [8277a] [28460q] [17488n] [8275au] [|domain]
```

Arpinging Host2 from Host 1 also works fine:

```
Host1 > arping 10.1.0.92
ARPING 10.1.0.92
60 bytes from aa:bb:cc:00:00:92 (10.1.0.92): index=0 time=104.200 usec
60 bytes from aa:bb:cc:00:00:92 (10.1.0.92): index=1 time=133.023 usec
60 bytes from aa:bb:cc:00:00:92 (10.1.0.92): index=2 time=108.228 usec
```

I wonder what I am missing or what component of the linux network stack decides, that things are sent to the gateway instead of the host directly.

Any pointer/help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to answer as I'm not the networking expert, but I'm not surprised that packets go via the gateway when seeing those routes.

Comment: Do you see this behavior with any port number, or just certain ones?

Comment: Are there routing rules in place that would select an alternate behavior? `ip rule` (is there more than the 3 usual entries?). If Docker is involved in any way but you omitted to tell about it, don't forget to mention it. Usually to simplify network problems, the very first thing to do is to disable completely Docker and reboot, then try again.